# Design and developer interaction

Tags: interaction-design

Q1. What's the best way to handover the prototype to the developers?

Q2. What's the right stage to interact with developers? During requirements stage along with PM, or during Ideation stage or when the design is done?

Comment: What's your assumption about software-development stages (waterfall process model)? Please explain abbreviations when introduced: `PM` to me means _project manager_?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final product is joint effort between design and development. A design that the developer cannot build will never see the light of day. Involve development as early as possible. How? That depends on the individual designer and developer. Talk about what every team member prefers, every individual works differently.

The involvement of development is usually little in the beginning and grows while you move from an idea to a user story. In *ideation* keep development in the loop on what is coming up and what you are thinking. Getting closer to a final product (*prototype*) increase involvement of development. This should make handover easier. After this the work of the designer is also not done, there are ad hoc questions or edge cases that might come up.

[image: Gradual handover between design and development]